# String comparison fails in Fortran 90 using TCP

Tags: string, macos, fortran90, gfortran, logical-operators

Some of you may have read my previous question about TCP with Fortran from a few days ago.  I got the issue I was having resolved but have now run into a new issue.

When I try to compare a string that is sent from the client to the server the comparison always fails.  This is the code that I have for the server:

```
!   To compile:
!   gfortran  server.f90 -o server.x -L"../../../libmsock/libmsock/" -lmsock
!   change path to libmsock to reflect your system

PROGRAM MSockets_server
    USE ISO_C_BINDING  !use this for ability to use c code
    USE MSockets  ! this provides the bindings to the c functions for TCP

    implicit none

    character(72) ::  process
!   .....................Initializations for TCP..............................
    INTEGER(C_SHORT)                    :: port
    INTEGER(C_INT)                      :: sockfd
    CHARACTER(KIND=C_CHAR, LEN=102400)  :: buffer
    INTEGER(CC_SIZE_T)                  :: count
    INTEGER(C_INT)                      :: length, error

!   ..........................Begin Processes.................................

!   Opening the socket
    port=HUGE(port) ! Most likely unused port
    sockfd=ServerSocket(port,2_c_int) ! It will return only once a connection is made
    IF(sockfd<0) STOP "Failed to open server socket"

    write(6,*) "Simulator Connected!"

    do
        length = sockGets(sockfd,buffer,int(len(buffer),CC_SIZE_T))
        if(length<0) exit
        if(length>0) then
            read(buffer,*) process  ! interpretting data sent into buffer
            write(6,*) process
            write(6,*) process == 'test' !This always evaluates to false even if process is "test"
            stop
        endif
    enddo

    stop
END PROGRAM !program
```

I cannot figure out why this comparison is failing when I enter "test" on the client side.  Can someone see a mistake I am making?

If you would like to try this out you can access a repository with all the files at: https://aliounis@bitbucket.org/aliounis/client_server_interaction.git

To compile you will need to download the files from http://www.muquit.com/muquit/software/libmsock/libmsock.html and compile them first.

I am compiling using gfortran.

Thanks for your help,

Andrew

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The second case works.  Thanks for your help.  If you would like to make this comment an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Make sure that the call to sockGets isn't appending a trailing null.  If it is the equality comparison will fail, because the character literal 'test' doesn't have a trailing null.

Comment: @IanH That may be what is causing the issue, but High Performance Mark's answer successfully got around the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the string returned to `process` is null-terminated and doesn't quite match `test`.  I'd try this comparison: `process(1:4) == 'test'`

Comment: Just so everyone know, the second part of this is what provided the solution for me.